# Variant of variants in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variant

I have the following variant

```
std::variant<Type1, Type2<subType1>> myVariant;
```

Type2 is a template class, there are 2 possible sub types subType1, and subType2 are possible.
Is the following supported?

`std::variant<Type1, Type2<std::variant<subType1,subType2>> myVariant;`

If yes, how would `get<index>(myVariant)` work with the inner variant?

edit: fix typo

Comment: That depends entirely on what `Type2<T>` is, how its interface works, and how you access whatever the `T` means to `Type2`. What `Type2<T>` does with its `T` depends on the type. It could store one `T`, or an array of `T`s or anything else. There's nothing specifically for C++ or `variant` to support; this is all in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `std::variant` is a new type and is distinct from all the types it can hold. Just like a good old union:

```
union int_or_double {
    int i;
    double d;
};
```

which is neither an `int` nor a `double` but a distinct type that can hold either an `int` value or a `double` value.

So here `std::variant<Type1, Type2<std::variant<subType1,subType2>> myVariant;` cannot only hold values of `Type2<std::variant<subType1,subType2>>` but neither `Type2<subType1>`, nor `Type2<subType2>` (and of course `Type1`...).

In real world programming, I think that `std::variant<Type1, Type2<subType1>, Type2<subType2>>` would be much simpler to use...

Comment: thank you `std::variant<Type1, Type2<subType1>, Type2<subType2>> ` is the what I'll be doing.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the following supported?

Yes, but not in the way you think.

```
std::variant<Type1, Type2<std::variant<subType1, subType2>>> myVariant;
```

is the same thing as:

```
using SomeType = Type2<std::variant<subType1, subType2>>;
std::variant<Type1, SomeType> myVariant;
```

The fact that `SomeType` is templated changes nothing to how the variant works. So:

> If yes, how would get(myVariant) work with the inner variant?

`get<index>(myVariant)` will return either a `Type1` or a `Type2<std::variant<subType1, subType2>>`. The inner variant does not come into play in any way shape or form.